# How to integrate a discord login button to my website

Tags: html, css

I am desperately looking for a way to integrate a "login with discord" button in my website. I can't find even a snippet or a widget button to put on my form. Even on github.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need a "login with discord" button? You haven't explained it in the question?

Answer (score -1):

use button or linked text with link of you discord invite link

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

for more https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_links.asp